# What does making the sys_read system call to linux put in the register eax?

Tags: assembly, nasm

When making a system call sys_read (int80h with the value 3 in eax) in the assembler, what will be stored in the register eax after the call is made? Is it the number of characters in the string that was read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) documentations:

> **Return Value**
>
> **On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file)**, and the file position is advanced by this number. It is
>   not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
>   requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are
>   actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
>   end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a
>   terminal), or because `read()` was interrupted by a signal. **On
>   error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately**. In this
>   case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any)
>   changes.

*Hint*: to find the documentations of `sys_foo`, type `man 2 foo`, `2` means [system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/).

Comment: Right, but on error, -ERRNO is in `eax`, not -1 like it says in the man pages. Reading from the terminal (stdin) the count in `eax` includes the linefeed (0xA) that ends input.